# Prevent submit empty textbox in Windows 8 Metro Application

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps

is there any control like RequiredFeild control (asp.net) in windows 8 metro? I have a simple form with several text boxes and I just want to make sure to prevent submit it when a textbox is empty. I know it can be easy in code but I'm eager to know are there any alternative ways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to use [WinRT XAML Toolkit](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/):

> **TextBoxValidationExtensions** - extensions that allow to specify the
>   Format of the requested Text input as well as brushes to use to
>   highlight a TextBox with valid or invalid Text.

I'm assuming you actually want to validate the input.

Answer (score 1):

this is another solution that I found.

[Here](http://blogs.u2u.be/diederik/post/2012/10/09/Input-Validation-in-Windows-8-Store-apps.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use String.IsNullOrEmpty() ?